# Intersection of 2d and 1d Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, intersection

For every element in array `A[:,3:]` that is also in array `B`, I want to set the value to 0, which creates the array `result`

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 1, 10, 101, 102, 103,   0,   0],
              [2, 2, 10, 102, 108,   0,   0,   0],
              [3, 3, 11, 101, 102, 106, 107, 108]])

B = np.array([101, 106, 108])

result = np.array([[1, 1, 10,   0, 102, 103,   0,   0],
                   [2, 2, 10, 102,   0,   0,   0,   0],
                   [3, 3, 11,   0, 102,   0, 107,   0]])
```

I know there is a way to do this using `in1d` and broadcasting `A` as a 1D array, but I have no idea how to go about this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you feed in that sliced 2D array `A[:,3:]` to [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html), it would flatten it to a 1D array and compare with `B` for occurrences and thus create a 1D mask, which could be reshaped and used for boolean indexing into that sliced  array  to set the `TRUE` elements to `zeros`. A one-liner implementation would look something like this -

```
A[:,3:][np.in1d(A[:,3:],B).reshape(A.shape[0],-1)] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [37]: A
Out[37]: 
array([[  1,   1,  10, 101, 102, 103,   0,   0],
       [  2,   2,  10, 102, 108,   0,   0,   0],
       [  3,   3,  11, 101, 102, 106, 107, 108]])

In [38]: np.in1d(A[:,3:],B) # Flattened mask
Out[38]: 
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
       False,  True, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [39]: np.in1d(A[:,3:],B).reshape(A.shape[0],-1) # Reshaped mask
Out[39]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [40]: A[:,3:][np.in1d(A[:,3:],B).reshape(A.shape[0],-1)] = 0 # Final code

In [41]: A
Out[41]: 
array([[  1,   1,  10,   0, 102, 103,   0,   0],
       [  2,   2,  10, 102,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  3,   3,  11,   0, 102,   0, 107,   0]])
```

---

To make things simpler, you could create a view of the flattened `A` and use the 1D mask obtained from `np.in1d` to have a more elegant solution. For a solution that changes only the sliced `A[:,3:]`, you can use `.flat` and then index like so -

```
A[:,3:].flat[np.in1d(A[:,3:],B)] = 0
```

For a case when you would like to set matching ones across entire `A`, you can use `.ravel()` -

```
A.ravel()[np.in1d(A,B)] = 0
```

I know `.ravel()` is a view and from the docs, it seems `.flat` doesn't create a copy either, so these should be *cheap*.

Comment: This is great, didn't realize I could do it with indexing.  Would I be able to use the same approach if I wasn't feeding in a sliced array, but instead the full array `A`?

Comment: @user3357979 Yup! Same approach should work there too. So, something like `A[np.in1d(A,B).reshape(A.shape[0],-1)] = 0`.

Comment: Just a warning, this will modify `A` in place, not give you a `result` array: you'll lose the original `A`, in case that matters.

Comment: @askewchan Surely! I am assuming that OP is aware of that :)

Answer (score -2):

Here's a way to do this without using `in1d()`. You can use the regular Python `in`  operator with a `ravel`-ed version of your array:

```
listed = [aa  in B for aa in A[:, 3:].ravel()]

# mask for unaffected left columns of A
mask1 = np.array([False]*A.shape[0]*3)
mask1.shape = (A.shape[0], 3)

# mask for affected right columns of A
mask2 = np.array(listed)
mask2.shape = (A.shape[0], A.shape[1]-3)

# join masks together so you have a mask with same dimensions as A
mask = np.hstack((mask1, mask2))

result  = A.copy()
result[mask] = 0
```

Or more succinctly:

```
listed = [aa  in B for aa in A[:, 3:].ravel()]
listed_array = np.array(listed)
listed.shape = (A.shape[0], A.shape[1]-3)
A[:, 3:][listed_array] = 0
```

You're probably better off with `in1d()` but it's nice to know there are other options.