# How to index numpy array on subset of array of bools that is smaller than numpy array's dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy

My question is inspired by another one: [Intersection of 2d and 1d Numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481491/intersection-of-2d-and-1d-numpy-array/32483377#32483377)  I am looking for a succinct solution that does not use `in1d`

The setup is this. I have a `numpy array` of `bools` telling me which values of `numpy array A` I should set equal to 0, called `listed_array`. However, I want to ignore the information in the first 3 columns of `listed_array` and only set A to zero as indicated in the other columns of listed_array.

I know the following is incorrect:

```
A[listed_array[:, 3:]] = 0
```

I also know I can pad this subset of `listed_array` with a call to `hstack`, and this will yield correct output, but **is there something more succinct?**

Comment: Do `A` and `listed_array` have the same shape?

Comment: And if so, does that mean you don't want to change anything in the first three columns of `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, this should do it:

```
A[:, 3:][listed_array[:, 3:]] = 0
```

which is a concise version of

```
mask3 = listed_array[:, 3:]
A3 = A[:, 3:]   # This slice is a *view* of A, so changing A3 changes A.
A3[mask3] = 0
```

Comment: yes of course! I feel silly having missed this. thank you.